# Where is pip in Python 2.7.9 (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, pip

I realize this question may be really stupid, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where I can find pip when installing python 2.7.9. I know that pip is bundled in this version and above, but I still can't find it. I do not have regular write permission, nor do I have a package manager so I installed Python 2.7.9 by downloading the linux binaries from their website, then

```
./configure --prefix=/home/me/software/python-2.7.9/myinstall/
```

then

```
make; make install
```

Everything seems to work correctly and I can run python after installing this way, but pip is nowhere to be found. Any help would be appreciated.

## Update

Running `python get-pip.py` yields the following error message:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20204, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 152, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpGmhhtn/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpGmhhtn/pip.zip/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpGmhhtn/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpGmhhtn/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 81, in load_module
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'
```

(sorry for the length).

## Update 2

Running `python -m ensurepip -vvv -U` I am given this error:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/me/software/Python-2.7.9/_centos5/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.6 requires SSL/TLS
```

Comment: what does `which pip` output?

Comment: /usr/bin/which: no pip in path/morepath...

Comment: install pip using https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py python get-pip.py installing using python you installed

Comment: How about `find /home/me/software/python-2.7.9/myinstall/ -type f -name "pip*"`?

Comment: @StevenKryskalla `./lib/python2.7/ensurepip/_bundled/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
./lib/python2.7/pipes.py
./lib/python2.7/pipes.pyc
./lib/python2.7/pipes.pyo`

Comment: does `python -m pip install somepackage` work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham your command yields `python: module pip not found`. Also I do realize that I could externally install pip, but that doesn't answer my question. I want to know why I can't find pip though it should be bundled with 2.7.9.

Comment: what does `which python` output?

Comment: which python outputs: `/home/me/software/python-2.7.9/myinstall/bin/python`

Comment: do you see pip in dist-packages  or site-packages?

Comment: if you try installing using get-pip do you get an error?

Comment: I do not see pip in either of those directories. I did a full find command and no pip showed up. I'll try installing with get-pip and will update in a few minutes.

Comment: http://code.krypto.org/python/hashlib/ install that after installing openssl, if openssl is installed you may need yum install -y openssl-devel

Comment: did yo solved?  I have same issue

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to use the [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ensurepip.html) package.

```
python -m ensurepip
```

This will install pip if it is not already there.

Comment: This gives me `ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):...`

Comment: @E.Cross In that case I'd just install `pip` with https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html for more details.

Comment: @E.Cross, that looks like an ssl problem

Comment: I did read about that, although I have no idea how to fix the ssl problem. I am not sure if I need to install openssl (which seems to be for solaris where I have centos5)

Comment: @E.Cross: what happens if you run `python -m ensurepip -vvv -U`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but on a windows computer. re-opening the command prompt as admin by right clicking and *run as an andministrator* and then trying

```
python -m ensurepip
```

again worked and successfully installed pip and I am now able to install other modules as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question on Linux. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).